# How can I temporarily hide reminders in Google Inbox?

Tags: inbox-by-gmail

I love the reminder functionality of Google Inbox. I mainly use it as a way to save links I want to look at later.

I know you can select 'Reminders' in the menu to see only reminders, but I often want to see just my mail without seeing reminders.

Is there a way to temporarily hide reminders?

Comment: Snooze them. See [Snooze emails & reminders until later - Inbox by Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/inbox/answer/6067583?hl=en)

Comment: @Rubén, It's a start, but I would want to snooze all the reminders with one action, and I've been unable to manage that.

Comment: Consider to submit a feature request through Google Inbox itself > Menu > Help and Feedback > Send Feedback

Comment: @Rubén, will do. I'm also putting together a chrome extension that will do it, as an interim solution. Will post it once it works.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because **Inbox by Gmail** was retired in April, 2019 and is no longer available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to just see email messages and not reminders, add this to your search box:

```
in:inbox
```

Answer (score 1):

As a quick fix for Chrome, I installed [this Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/poakhlngfciodnhlhhgnaaelnpjljija/related?hl=en), and added the following custom JavaScript to Google Inbox:

```
$(function(){
    $('ul.pa.Y').append('<li class="oin9Fc cN just-mail" role="menuitem"><img class="io navIconDone" src="//ssl.gstatic.com/bt/C3341AA7A1A076756462EE2E5CD71C11/ic_product_inbox_16dp_r2_2x.png" srcset="//ssl.gstatic.com/bt/C3341AA7A1A076756462EE2E5CD71C11/ic_product_inbox_16dp_r2_2x.png 2x" alt="" aria-hidden="true" jsan="7.io,7.navIconDone,8.src,0.srcset,0.alt,0.aria-hidden" jstcache="990"><span class="sM" ti ee" jsan="7.sM,t-lp4cLVwXzdE,0.title,t-UXknpQ1iPuE" jstcache="991">Just Mail</span></li>');
    $('ul.pa.Y').children().first().addClass('inbox-button');
    $('<style>.hidden { display:none; }</style>').appendTo('body');
    $('.just-mail').on('click', function(){
        $('div.scroll-list-item.top-level-item').each(function(index){
            var item_id = $( this ).data('item-id');
            var thread_type = item_id.split(':')[1].split('-')[1];
            if(thread_type == 'a'){
               $(this).addClass('hidden');
            }   
        });
    
        $( this ).addClass('hA').siblings('.hA').removeClass('hA');
    });

    $('.inbox-button').on('click', function(){
        $('div.scroll-list-item.top-level-item').each(function(index){
            var item_id = $( this ).data('item-id');
            var thread_type = item_id.split(':')[1].split('-')[1];
            if(thread_type == 'a'){
                $(this).removeClass('hidden');
            }   
        } );
    
        $('.just-mail').removeClass('hA');
    });
});
```

The JavaScript adds a "Just Mail" item to the side menu of Inbox, which can be selected to hide the reminders. To see the reminders again, select the "Inbox" menu item in the same menu.

If you use this solution, you will need to update the JavaScript every now and then to be compatible with the updates made by Google. The above code has already stopped working. The accepted solution is more future-proof.